# Normal vector of $\Gamma \times \mathbb{R}^+$ where $\Gamma$ is compact hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $\Gamma$ be a smooth boundaryless hypersurface of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $Q=\Gamma \times \mathbb{R}^+$.

What does a normal vector of $Q$ look like? Because I want to compute the normal derivative of a function $f:Q \to \mathbb{R}$.

Do we need a normal vector of $\Gamma$ find this?

Comment: $Q$ is a submanifold of what?

Comment: Just Euclidean space.

Comment: $R^{n+1}$ or $R^n$

Comment: The line is a hypersurface of the plane and its product with $R^+$ is a sunmanifold of the plane and also is a hypersurface of $R^3$

Comment: I guess $Q$ would be in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Assume that the normal to $\Gamma$ is $u$, the the normal to $Q$ is $(u,o)$

Answer (score 3):

$Q$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with boundary (a cylinder to be more specific). On the interior of $Q$ the normal vector is nothing else than the normal vector to $\Gamma$ with a zero $n+1$ component. The boundary of $Q$ has codimension $2$ hence you have two independent normal vectors. One is again the vector defined before, and the other one is $e_{n+1}$ the unit versor of the last coordinate in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

**addendum** after more details given in the comments. It seems that you are interested in the vector which is tangent to the the hypersurface $Q$ and normal to the boundary $\partial Q$. Such a vector is $(0,-1)$ with $0\in \mathbb R^n$. If the variables of $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^+$ are $(y,x)$ then the normal derivative of a function $u$ would be $-\partial u / \partial x$.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose we write $y \in \Gamma$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^+.$ Is it correct then to write the normal vector $\nu= (-1, 0)$ (where the $0$ is the zero in $\Gamma$)? Because I saw that "the normal derivative of $u$ = $-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$."

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused as to why you want to take a normal vector in the interior... consider the simple case of a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, no one ever talks about taking a normal vector anywhere except on the boundary.

Comment: @sequitor: consider a disk in $R^3$.

Comment: @XipanXiao I don't understand, what do you mean?